# Common partition for Windows 8.1 and Linux

Tags: linux, windows-8, partitioning

Which filesystem should I use in order to be able to mount the partition in Windows 8.1 and in Linux?

This partition should be used to exchange files between two operating systems. This mean that I would like both operating systems to write to this partition and minimum data lost due to data corruption.

Will it be possible to read btrfs from Windows 8.1?

Comment: FAT32 is usable by both. Or if you can have the 'shared' folder on a network drive, then it does not matter what FS you use.

Comment: @Darius, i would prefer not to use network drive...

Answer (score 2):

btrfs cannot be read by Windows 8.1 - your options are FAT32 and NTFS.  NTFS is far superior to FAT32 and will handle any file system errors better than FAT32.

However, NTFS must be "closed" by the OS to be considered clean when opened.  Prior to Windows 8, shutting down Windows would be sufficient to close an NTFS file system.  However, Windows 8 has "Fast Start", which maintains state about the file system and other parts of the OS between boot sessions.

So when you boot linux, the NTFS partition will error.  You would need to disable fast start:

```
Control Panel / Hardware and Sound / Power Options / System Setting / Choose what the power buttons do
```

Uncheck the `Turn on fast startup`.